# Count the number of characters in string "m". Save the number in variable "numbers"

Tags: for-loop, range

m = "learning Python is fun but it is so hard!"

Could you please write the code without using len() function? I am learning range and for function, it is one of the questions that I haven't figured out.
Thanks!

Comment: I actually figured it out. 
 
m = "learning Python is fun but it is so hard!"
numbs = sum(1 for i in m)
print(numbs)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the characters using `for`:

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> m = "learning Python is fun but it is so hard!"
>>> for char in m:
...   sum = sum + 1
... 
>>> print(sum)
41
```

Comment: Thanks! That is much easier!